# 3ds max: Copy, Instance, Reference - a similar function in the blender. An example of the 3ds max, is in the description

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, parent, append, splines

I have a question that I can't find an answer to anywhere. More precisely, I do not know how to ask such a question correctly in order to find an answer to it.
I am interested in whether there is something similar in the Blender as in 3ds max? https://3dtuts.by/chem-otlichayutsya-variantyi-klonirovaniya-copy-instance-i-reference/ In a nutshell, I need to: create an object-1, create a copy of it-object 2. I want that, in the editing mode, moving the vertices of object 1, the same vertices automatically move, but in object 2.
Аlso, it is very desirable that such a function extends to splines (curve) as well.

Comment: Select the object, and press Alt+D, creates a so called *linked duplicate* -> https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html

Comment: Thank you very much, friend! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @brockmann I have duplicated your comment as an answer. At your request, I would take it down. I say this because it got an upvote and a downvote, and IDK if it was you, so there you are.

Comment: Not mine @TheLabCat. I'd suggest, search for a dupe though, had no time yesterday... Such basics already have an answer, IMHO we should respect that effort from years ago instead of repeating the same stuff over and over again by duplicating a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brockmann said, you can create a linked duplicate of an object that shares the same mesh data block. However, if you’ve created a duplicate object with a duplicate mesh data block and wish to change it, you can also go to the mesh properties tab in the Properties  editor while the duplicate object is selected, and change the mesh data block to the original one, and the two objects will be “linked.” You can even do this for objects that at first have mesh data blocks that did not come from each other.

Comment: Manual link: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html